# Multiple Ec2 instances on Amazon free aws account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I created amazon micro instance with IP ec2@x.x.x.x.com .

While using amazon free service, if I create 2nd micro instance then will it be chargable? or only one micro instance is available on for free services. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 750 hours a month of micro instances on a free account. Since there are between 672 and 745 hours in a month, that means you can run one instance 24x7. You can run more instances for less time, if you want, but be sure not to go over 750 instance-hours in a month, or you will be charged. You can confirm this and check other free tier allowances [here](http://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Comment: thanks, means I use 5 instance each around 50 hours per month, then no charge right? Can you please tell me how this hours usage get counted?

Comment: You're charged an hour for each hour that the instance is running at all, even if only for a few seconds. So if you start an instance at 08:59:30 and stop it again a minute later at 09:00:30, you'll be charged for two hours -- 08:00-09:00 and 09:00-10:00 -- since it was running in both of those hours.

Comment: generally once someone create intance, it keep working. Like someone hosted site then it has to be working all time. so 24*30=  720 would be considered any way that website is being used or not, right? if I have two instance running then 720* 2 = 1440 hours per month. is that correct?

Comment: any suggestion for previous comment

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you keep your instances running all the time then they use between 672 and 745 hours per month. It doesn't matter if they're at 0% CPU usage or 100% CPU usage, just whether they're in the "Running" state or not.